# SQLiteDatabase delete(table_name, null, null) is not deleting all rows in the table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my code :

```
Db.getInstance().beginTransaction();
int i = Db.getInstance().delete("friends", null, null);
Log.e(TAG, "dropDB: " + i);
Db.getInstance().setTransactionSuccessful();
Db.getInstance().endTransaction();
```

I have searched the SO community, but cannot find what is wrong in this code. When I delete , the value of i is number of rows deleted, but still the database keeps returning rows.
Db is my own helper class in which I initialise the SQLiteDatabase's object and get `getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: Do you have nested transactions? What does the "keeps returning rows" specifically mean?

Comment: I mean i returns the number of rows affected, in this case, deleted

Comment: What I'd first do, to check is, after the above code, to use `Cursor csr = Db.getInstance().query("friends",null,null,null,null,null,null,null); Log.d(TAG,"friends now has" + Integer.toString(csr.getCount()) + "rows");`. *Might have typos as I haven't checked.*

Answer (score 0):

May be nothing, but try only calling getInstance() once and setting it to a variable.

Comment: I don't think that is it, getInstance() will always return the object , Db is a singleton

Answer (score 0):

I use this in a CustomDialog when the user clicks the btnYES to delete the table. 
I know the table only ever has one record because it hold a password so try this

```
                db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

            String q = "SELECT * FROM masterPW";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);
            // Above query gets TABLE_PW data from Col_IDI
            // TABLE_PW will only ever have one row of data

            int rowID = 99;
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                rowID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_IDI));
                str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_MPW));
            }
            cursor.close();

            // Line of code below WORKS deletes entire TABLE <=====
            // Not a recommended way to re-set the master password
            // db.delete(TABLE_PW, null, null);
```